# Change spacing for lists in LyX through template

Tags: spacing, lists, lyx, templates, moderncv

I want to change the vertical spacing of a list in my resume.  I am using the moderncv style file through LyX in Ubuntu 12.04.

One of the list environments defined in the moderncv is Computer Skills. I find the spacing between items too big, so I want to reduce it.

I also found an instruction that changes the spacing.  If I add a quote in the preamble, the spacing in the list becomes small but the spacing in all other entries also gets reduced.  In the style file, the code that relates to the quote is this:

```
% optional quote
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}
  {}
  {\centering{\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}
\end{minipage}}\\[2.5em]}%
```

However, I don't understand how any of these commands would change the spacing either in the itemize section or outside of it.

In any case, my question is on how to modify the spacing for the Computer items, and how to modify the spacing between other entries in that style.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I really don't understand the questio. Can you add a minimal working example?

Comment: It's been a while.  I think I remember what was going on.  I'll take a look and edit the question.